# Showing SEM model as figure - report unstandardized or standardized values?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, standardization, confirmatory-factor

I want to show results of a CFA in two figures, proposing a 7 factor model and a 7 factor model with a major general factor.

Now I wonder whether it's better to report the full standardized solution (stand. latent and manifest variables) or unstandardized solution of the estimates?

Can you give me a rationale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if the unstandardized estimates are informative, that should be used. If they're not, then use the standardized. If, for example, you had a variable (say, gender) predicting the latent variable(s) then the unstandardized estimates are informative, because they tell you about the change in the latent variable in the scale on which the questions were asked.

If the units are not informative, and they're usually not in a CFA, then use the standardized estimates.